# Spatiotemporal patterns around continuous phase transitions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, computational-physics

Consider the Ising model near criticality, a clear spatiotemporal pattern emerges, with scale free clusters shifting around in space, over time. Similar behaviour can be observed in the voter model, near criticality.

More complex spatiotemporal patterns can be found the Olami Feder Christensen model, when the dissipation parameter $\alpha$ is tuned at $0.25$, where we the system becomes once again critical.

Generally, it seems to me that numerous models exhibit spatiotemporal patterns near a continuous phase transition point. I am wondering if there any theory behind this phenomenon, of spatiotemporal pattern formation near criticality.

Comment: I guess this is related to the correlation length in both time and space diverging. But maybe I don't quite understand by "spatiotemporal pattern"

Comment: Yes, the correlation length does diverge as you say. But the resulting patterns can have different shapes and forms. For example, the patches of the Olami Feder Christensen can immediately be distinguished by eye, from the patterns that the Ising model produces on criticality. 
I am wondering if there any theory studying the variability of these structure that arise near criticality.